# Unexpected output

Tags: winapi, executable, exe, portable-executable

The following code is supposed to print out the names of all the sections in the specified exe (c:\linked list.exe in this case), but it produces some bizarre output.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<Windows.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<WinNT.h>

int main()
{
    FILE *fp; 
    int i;

    if((fp = fopen("c:\\Linked List.exe","rb"))==NULL)
        std::cout<<"unable to open";


    IMAGE_DOS_HEADER imdh;
    fread(&imdh,sizeof(imdh),1,fp);


    IMAGE_NT_HEADERS imnth;
    fread(&imnth,sizeof(imnth),1,fp);

    IMAGE_SECTION_HEADER *pimsh;
    pimsh = (IMAGE_SECTION_HEADER *)malloc(sizeof(IMAGE_SECTION_HEADER) * imnth.FileHeader.NumberOfSections);

    fread(pimsh,sizeof(IMAGE_SECTION_HEADER),imnth.FileHeader.NumberOfSections,fp);

    for(i=0;i<imnth.FileHeader.NumberOfSections;i++)
    {
        printf("%s\n",pimsh->Name);
        pimsh++;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the issue with you code, is which you  are not reading for the correct location the IMAGE_NT_HEADERS struture, you must set the offset of the file to the value of `imdh.e_lfanew`  using  `fseek(fp, imdh.e_lfanew, 0);` and then read the `IMAGE_NT_HEADERS` record.

Try this modified code.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include<iostream>
#include<Windows.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<WinNT.h>

int main()
{
    FILE *fp; 
    int i;

    if((fp = fopen("c:\\Linked List.exe","rb"))==NULL)
        std::cout<<"unable to open";

    IMAGE_DOS_HEADER imdh;
    fread(&imdh,sizeof(imdh),1,fp);

    //set the pointer of the file to the location of the IMAGE_NT_HEADERS record
    fseek(fp, imdh.e_lfanew, 0);
    IMAGE_NT_HEADERS imnth;
    fread(&imnth,sizeof(imnth),1,fp);

    IMAGE_SECTION_HEADER *pimsh;
    pimsh = (IMAGE_SECTION_HEADER *)malloc(sizeof(IMAGE_SECTION_HEADER) * imnth.FileHeader.NumberOfSections);

    fread(pimsh,sizeof(IMAGE_SECTION_HEADER),imnth.FileHeader.NumberOfSections,fp);

    for(i=0;i<imnth.FileHeader.NumberOfSections;i++)
    {
        printf("%s\n",pimsh->Name);
        pimsh++;
    }

    getchar();
}
```

Also take a look to these articles about the PE Format.

- [An In-Depth Look into the Win32 Portable Executable File Format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc301805.aspx)
- [Peering Inside the PE: A Tour of the Win32 Portable Executable File Format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms809762.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible to remove the DOS Stub from an Image. If this stub exists, the Windows Loader ignores it. If this stub does not exist, the Windows Loader is happy with it.